# Onsen UI におけるラジオボタンの仕様について

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

Onsen UI におけるラジオボタンの仕様について

Monaca 上で Onsen UI を使ってアプリを制作しています。

Onsen UI のラジオボタンを使用しているのですが、項目の文面が長いとチェック欄の部分まで折り返しが発生してしまいます。

見た目が美しくないのでチェック欄に掛からないようにインテンド（？）を掛けたいのですが、それは可能でしょうか？

「仕様なのでできない」ということでしたら、他の方法を検討します。

```
<li class="list__item list__item--tappable">
<label class="radio-button radio-button--list-item">
<input type="radio" name="Kousei_Q" value="2">
<div class="radio-button__checkmark radio-button--list-item__checkmark"></div>
Ａ．喋りかけたり、相手の様子をみて、どういう立場の人か探る
</label>
</li>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

あまりイケてないですが、widthを指定して調整してみるとか。

```
<li class="list__item list__item--tappable" style="width: 200px;">
    <label class="radio-button radio-button--list-item">
        <input type="radio" name="Kousei_Q" value="2">
        <div class="radio-button__checkmark radio-button--list-item__checkmark"></div>
        <span style="float: right; width: 150px;">
            Ａ．喋りかけたり、相手の様子をみて、どういう立場の人か探る
        </span>
    </label>
</li>
```

Comment: アドバイスいただいた方法でそれっぽくなりました。
（width を 90% にしたら収まりが良くなりました）
とりあえず当座はこれでしのごうと思います。

    <li class="list__item list__item--tappable">
        <label class="radio-button radio-button--list-item">
            <input type="radio" name="Kousei_Q" value="2">
            <div class="radio-button__checkmark
            radio-button--list-item__checkmark"></div>
            <span style="float: right; width: 90%;">
            Ａ．喋りかけたり、相手の様子をみて、どういう立場の人か探る
            </span>
        </label>
    </li>